# What to expect about the mobile phone usage during a flight to China and based on the CAAC regulations

Tags: usa, china, internet, wifi, china-southern-airlines

I recently booked a flight departing from the US to China from China Southern Airlines and while reading some info on their website related to the inflight entertainment I found this about the Wifi service:

> In accordance with the regulations of  CAAC, mobile phone must be
>   turned off  throughout the flight. Please bring laptop  or tablet PC
>   with the Wi-Fi function.

*(Obtained from: http://www.csair.com/cn/czadscale/2016/20160628_0/20150627.html?subsite=AU_EN)*

So, I was surprised to read something like that and I wonder how the airline crew is going to handle this. In other words, are they really strict and it means that I won’t be able to even use my mobile phone in airplane mode and just for listening music?

Just FYI, CAAC is the Civil Aviation Administration of China.

Comment: I didn't fly recently on CSA, but I flew a lot of China Eastern, they have the same rules for flights, and they are mostly ignored.

Comment: @GeorgeY. Really? I already traveled and I must say that China Southern respect the rules, the airline crew was always looking if someone was using mobile phones and even warned some people but were never rude. Anyway, I can even say that during a flight departing from China to Bangkok I saw a, let’s say, “police officer” walking from time to time in the airplane (a bit weird) but that was all and now I know my answer - I guess - probably things vary from airline to airline.

Comment: Just FYI - one from the crew said in a moment that the restriction will be removed soon but who knows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't try. You [could end up in jail](http://china.org.cn/china/2017-02/09/content_40254608.htm).

> The third passenger, surnamed Wang, was taken for five days after landing at Beijing... Wang was punished for allegedly listening to music on cell phone during takeoff and landing.

Answer (score 3):

The regulations have finally been updated to allow airlines to make their own policies about the use of phones and electronic devices.

[China Eastern and Hainan Airlines now allow electronic devices to be used on-board](https://thepointsguy.com/2018/01/china-eastern-hainan-allow-ped-usage/), with phones in airplane mode. Other airlines will set their own rules.